# why strftime convert datetime to object format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strftime

i converted date from y/m/d to d/m/y format in a data-frame using

```
from pandas import pd


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d ').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

but after this code execute the `df['Date']` field become object format,when i try to convert datetimeformat it again become y/m/d form ,is there any solution for this?

Comment: There is no issue to fix. If you want to perform datetime functions then you keep it in the internal datetime type, which pandas has its own representation of. If you want to visually display it, you convert to object type

Comment: is  there any option to represent d/m/y form in datetimeformat

Comment: try `pd.to_datetime(df['Posting_date']).dt.round('1d')`

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df['Posting_date']).dt.round('1d') convert in y/m/d format